# Apple Auto-Renewable Subscriptions : Shared Secret

Tags: itunes, shared-secret

According to Apple iTune Connect document said that the "Shared Secret" section is in "Manage Your In App Purchases". But I could not find it. Do I have to change the iTune Connect setting to have this SECTION visible?

Best Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 23):

Yes, I had this problem, the auto-renewable subscription doesn't appear until you set a shared secret, and the shared secret section doesn't appear until you amend your contract.

Here's how I fixed it:

in iTunes connect go into "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" and click "Request" on the iOs paid apps contract, then accept the contract.

Then got onto the "Manage Your In App Purchases" section and the shared secret section will be there, click "generate shared secret"

Now if you create a new in app purchase you should now see "Auto Renewable" as an option on the list of in app purchase types.

Comment: It's the exactly answer what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on subscription in ios and run first as a demo then you have no need to do these things

> iTunes connect go into "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" and click "Request" on the iOs paid apps contract, then accept the contract.

Visit this link

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com

1:- Click on **Features**

2:- Click on **In-App Purchases** and create your subscription package

3:- After creating successfully subscription click on **App-Specific Shared Secret**

4:- Generate **App-Specific Shared Secret**

Comment: you can also view the Shared Secret key if it was previously generated